# Garbage collector and some event in angular 4

Tags: angular, garbage-collection

I use angular 4 to develop a program to display image.

When i run some function and profiler it i see the garbage collector use too much CPU ticks and some thing of angular i dont know what it is. Some one help me explain what is it and how improve the garbage collector dont use too much CPU.

[image]
Many thanks.